# Visual Flow with approval process

Tags: force.com, configuration

Hi Everyone I have a query about Visual Flows. Can I add Approval process to a visual flow. My scenario is I want to add new product to product master object (i.e custom object) by using visual flows but before adding product a approval should go to manager if manager approves then go to admin otherwise rejects.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Submitting an item for approval from a flow isn't currently possible -- at least not without apex coding. However, it will be available for Salesforce's Winter 15 Release.

See: http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_process_submit.htm

Our Sandboxes just updated and I'm checking it out now. Adding an approval looks pretty straightforward so this will be a nice improvement for us.